# How to use a unique_ptr reference to a vector element?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I just started learning C++.

In C I would just use `Node* cur_node`, but in C++ this doesn't work:

```
struct Node {
        int val;
};

struct Foo {
        unique_ptr<vector<Node>> nodes;
        unique_ptr<&Node> cur_node;
};


int main() {
        Foo foo;
        foo.nodes = make_unique<vector<Node>>();
        foo.nodes->push_back((Node){.val=100});
        //d.cur_node = d.nodes[0];
        foo.cur_node = make_unique<&Node>(((*d.nodes)[0]));
        (*d.nodes)[0].val = 200;
        cout << d.cur_node->val << endl;;
        cout << (*d.nodes)[0].val << endl;;
}


error: 'Node' does not refer to a value
        unique_ptr<&Node> cur_node;
```

If I don't use a reference, the value is copied, and I can't modify the original vector by modifying `cur_node`.

Maybe I need `shared_ptr` for this?

**edit**

To make it more clear: I want `cur_node` to contain a reference to one of the values in the vector, and to modify the original vector by modifying `cur_node`, just like I would with raw C pointers.

Thanks

Comment: The & isn't needed.

Comment: Could you explain in words what you are trying to do? Trying to guess how non-working code is supposed to work is not reliable.

Comment: Also, why do you need `unique_ptr<vector<Node>> nodes;`? Won't `vector<Node> nodes;` be enough?

Comment: The `cur_node` should always point to either none element or one of the nodes stored in `nodes`, but never to any other node?

Comment: The reason I ask is, that if that is the case then these two members should `protected` and the access/manipulation should be controlled by member function, otherwise this cannot be ensured. And if the access/manipulation is controlled by member function then you could use  `Node *` for `cur_node` you anyhow need to do something like that because references or pointers to the elements in `nodes` can/will become invalid when you add new elements to that vector.

Comment: @JaMiT I want `cur_node` contain a reference to one of the values in the vector, and to modify the original vector by modifying `cur_node`, just like I would with raw C pointers.

Comment: @t.niese no, cur_node value can change to any other node in the vector.

Comment: @Alex that's what I meant, that `cur_node` will always have to point to a node in `nodes` but never to a node that is not stored in that vector.

Comment: Thanks @t.niese. "can/will become invalid when you add new elements to that vector. " This is huge and I didn't realize that. I will be modifying the vector constantly, so a reference is not an option at all? I should use indexing instead, right?

Comment: @Alex An index and with getter like described in the answer of [Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868995/1960455) is the safest and most likely easiest implementation.

Comment: And you probably should get rid of the `unique_ptr<vector<Node>>` and replace it with `vector<Node>` an `unique_ptr` there looks just wrong, what's the purpose of that pointer? Making the vector optional? If so then you should use `std::optional`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `Node *`, however you need to be careful of the vector's [pointer invalidation rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

```
struct Foo {
    unique_ptr<vector<Node>> nodes;
    Node * cur_node;
};


int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.nodes = make_unique<vector<Node>>();
    foo.nodes->push_back((Node){.val=100});
    foo.cur_node = &d.nodes->at(0);
    d.nodes->at(0).val = 200;
    cout << d.cur_node->val << endl;;
    cout << d.nodes->at(0).val << endl;;
}
```

Why not just hold the index?

```
struct Foo {
    unique_ptr<vector<Node>> nodes;
    size_t cur_index; 
    Node & cur_node() { return nodes->at(cur_index); }
};


int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.nodes = make_unique<vector<Node>>();
    foo.nodes->push_back((Node){.val=100});
    foo.cur_index = 0;
    d.nodes->at(0).val = 200;
    cout << d.cur_node().val << endl;;
    cout << d.nodes->at(0).val << endl;;
}
```

Comment: `Node` has lots of fields, I want to be able to do `cur_node.x = x; cur_node.val = y` etc, otherwise I'd have to implement dozens of methods for that. I just read somewhere that a reference to a vector element can be unsafe, so I might just use indexing.

Comment: @Alex You can do `cur_node().x = x; cur_node().val = y;` just fine

Comment: Thanks @Caleth, that's exactly what I need

Comment: `d.nodes->at(0).get();` would not work. It is `unique_ptr<vector<Node>> nodes;` and not `unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Node>>> nodes;` So `d.nodes->at(0)` returns a reference to a `Node`. It would have to be `&d.nodes->at(0)`.

Comment: Also I wonder if it's going to affect performance calling the function for setting every field

Comment: @Alex it's unlikely to be measurable

Answer (score 0):

`unique_ptr` is a template. It doesn't need an `&` in the type. In fact, I don't think an `&` makes sense in there in this context at all in C++. `&` usually means the address of a concrete variable, not a type.

Just do this instead:

```
uniqure_ptr<Node> cur_node;
```

Comment: Thanks, like I said in the OP, I tried this, and I no longer could modify the original vector by modifying cur_node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use std::shared_ptr . Presuming `Node` is a large struct and don't want to store by value in `Foo` here's how you can do:

```
struct Foo {
    vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> cur_node;
};

int main()
{
    vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> vec = { make_shared<Node>(100 ), make_shared<Node>(200) };

    Foo foo;
    foo.nodes.push_back(vec[0]);

    cout << foo.nodes[0]->val << endl;
    cout << foo.cur_node->val << endl;
}
```